# How add new row in Gantt chart

Tags: javascript, anychart

How to add a custom row into Anychart Gant Table?

I can not find the necessary method in documentation. I want on button click open the modal window and create a new row.

Comment: Please, try something first and then ask your question. Post your codes, errors here.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Could you please add more information about your problem, maybe some code aswell ? You can refer to the [how to ask section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask/) to create a complete and answerable question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [addChild()](https://api.anychart.com/anychart.data.Tree#addChild) and [addChildAt()](https://api.anychart.com/anychart.data.Tree#addChildAt) methods of the dataTree. For details, check the method descriptions and samples of using. Via model window, you can fill the row content and apply it to the chart's dataTree using one of these methods.